# Azure: How can I find the owner or resource ID of a container registry?

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

## Background

A year or two ago, when I was learning Azure, I created a container registry (ACR).

I would now like to use that exact same name again. I can either use that same registry, or I would like to delete that registry and start again.  (It does not have anything useful on it that I do not have in other locations.)

But I cannot seem to figure out which subscription / resource group owns that registry.  I am *nearly certain* I know which one it was, but when I log on to that account, the registry is not there. To be clear, I tried to create it again but it said that the name was not available. It's a very weird name, so I am pretty sure it is still my old one sitting around somewhere.

## Question

- How can I find out the owner of a container registry?

In my case, it is a dumb mistake. But I have to imagine that companies will want a particular name, and even be willing to pay a little to have a particular registry name. Is there no way to query Azure to ask for the owner of a container registry?  What happens if I lost the "paperwork" for which subscription owns it, like in my case?

I was hoping for something like `az acr public show` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

> I was hoping for something like `az acr public show` or something like
> that

There is a CLI command like it:

```
az acr show --name acr_name
```

You can get all the information about your ACR, int includes the owner resource group and its resource Id. The resource Id will show you the subscription ID.

But when you use the CLI, it means you already login and uses the default subscription or set the current subscription. If you don't know which subscription the ACR in, you need to try this command in all the subscriptions your account has.

And for the owner of the ACR, you need to list all the assignment and filter with your requirements:

```
az role assignment list --role Owner --scope acr_resourceId
```

This CLI command can list all the owners directly to your ACR, but the list does not include the owners that inherit from the subscription.

Comment: Yes, but this only works for ACRs that are in my current subscription.  This is part of my problem:  I *thought* I knew the subscription, but when I went there, I found nothing.

I was looking for something that allowed for *public* information that can be freely shared, hence the `public` argument to my hoped-for command.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson I'm afraid there is nothing like the public in the CLI. It's a private registry. So the only public thing is the server URL like myacr.azurecr.io, not group, no subscription.

Comment: that's what I suspected.  I understand that you cannot see private information, but it seems so overly protected now that it is quite easy to lose your own registry, like I did. :(

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Yes, sometimes we may lose the info of the server. But you just can know the server URL as design, such as you won't know the info of a server that created by other people.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Well, if it solves your problem, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: No, @CharlesXu, it does not solve my problem.  As I said in my question, I wanted to know about registries for which I *do not* have the private information.  If your advice is helpful to others, that is great.  But I would rather not accept an answer that does not address the core issue. In case others have a similar problem, I want them to definitively know how to resolve it.  Or, in this case, I want them to know there is unfortunately (currently) no way to resolve it.  I appreciate your help, though.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson But you know there is no way to solve it from this answer. If all the communities ask for a no-solution issue, then SO will never exist. The accept answer does not mean only solved the issue, also means it's helpful to this issue when there is no way to solve it.